# Can I install FreeNAS on an old ReadyNAS 1100

Tags: truenas, readynas

I have an old ReadyNAS 1100 by Netgear. It has 4x500GB disks. http://kbserver.netgear.com/products/rnr4000.asp

Can I install FreeNAS on it? If so, can you please explain how?

As far as I can understand, the ReadyNAS has it's system in a FlashROM.

Does it have a load? BIOS?  Will putting FreeNAS on a USB help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ReadyNAS systems have custom made RISC CPUs, there's no BIOS (as you know it); currently FreeNAS only releases i386 and amd64 versions, and the on-board flash likely isn't big enough either.

Answer (score 1):

The ReadyNAS 1100 uses the SPARC IT1004, per the forum link below, so no, you can't install FreeNAS on it because of the processor and other reasons which are not obvious at the moment. It would be interesting project to port FreeNAS to it, but that's going to require lots of knowledge on using FreeBSD as an embedded operating system.

Netgear Forums: x6/600 vs duo vs stora?
http://www.readynas.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=34535

Comment: The Infrant IT1004 uses the Sparc ISA (not sure if it's V7 or V8), but Sparc is not a brand of processor. Given the lack of information about the architecture it'd be extremely difficult to port FreeBSD to it.